# callbacks function in drupal 7 elysia cron

Tags: php, cron, drupal-7, cron-task

```
function docusign_get_return($accountId, $apiClient){

  $getAllDocs = db_query("SELECT * FROM {my_docs} WHERE status = :status_text", array(':status_text' => 'sent'))->fetchAll();

  foreach($getAllDocs as $docs) {
      $get_status = 'completed';
      if($docs->status !== $get_status)
      {
          $update_doc_status = db_update('my_docs') // Table name no longer needs {}
        ->fields(array(
          'status' => $get_status,
        ))
        ->condition('doc_id', $docs->doc_id, '=')
        ->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

If I have a function like above in my callbacks.inc file. How can I run this function in elysia cron drupal 7? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Elysia Cron only works with modules, so you CAN'T run a callback function with ELysia cron. What you can do is create a module and insert that function into the module. And rename the function to MODULENAME_cron.

*Note: MODULENAME will be the name of your module. So if your module_name is test_module, then  rename the function to test_module_cron